# Several separate answers OR One answer with several nested answers?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering about an approach(a manner of answering) which can be used when I possess several solutions to a single question. How shall I tackle it? Shall I put each solution as a new answer or it is better to keep them merged?

Here are several examples of mine:

**Case 1.** One answer with several nested answers
Question: [Summing data from column in Attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/summing-data-from-column-in-attribute-table)
*Number of solutions:* Seven (7)

**Case 2.** Several separate answers
A Question: [Creating point at line end using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347762/creating-point-at-line-end-using-qgis)
*Number of solutions:* Three (3)

*My logic behind:* Simply saying in the Case 1, solutions are tiny and required roughly equal amount of efforts, therefore I decided to merge them. Albeit in the Case 2, I splitted answers because each required different efforts and each intended to solve a different purpose of the same task using alternative technology provided in QGIS.

Hopefully, I am thinking correct when I wanted to answer several times. Perhaps, there are some other better suggestions in handling several answers to a single question.

Comment: I like your logic (have used similar approach myself)! The only argument pro posting several answers I can think of are the one which allow voting to sort the best answer, but usually if there is one best approach among others in one answer, someone will leave a comment highlighting it. Posting several answers in one post is ok, but personally I don't like it (I feel I am spamming the site and my own metrics).

Comment: @AndreSilva Are you saying that you think multiple answers in a single answer to a question is OK generally and that you don’t think a user should post multiple answers as separate answers to the same question generally?

Comment: @PolyGeo, “yes” to first question (both methods are accepted); “no” to the second one. It os ok to post multiple separate answers as pointed out in the answers so far. But personally I avoid doing so. Either because it is what Aaron said in his last paragraph or because what OP said in his case 1. Generally, if I know more than one answer, I post the one I think it is the best. Sporadically, I will post an answer and come up with a better solution later. In this case, I just update my answer because with less amount of pots I can keep better track of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is precedent on this topic on Meta Stack Exchange:

[What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/641151)

The top voted answers indicate that multiple answers are perfectly acceptable and preferred. One of the strongest arguments for using multiple answers is that the top answer/s will be allowed to float to the top through the voting system.

I would add, however, that in some cases it would be preferable to include multiple answers in one post if you need to compare and contrast different approaches or methods.

Answer (score 8):

Post them as separate answers.

Why?

- clearer to view
- users can adress one specific of your solutions more easily (like putting a link to it somewhere else without having to tell which one they are referring to, or by commenting on it)
- "better" solutions can be upvoted to the top (or vice versa)
- you earn your deserved reputation for every single solution
- *more arguments to come..*

Exception:

- Your solutions are very similar or require a discussion between them

Contra:

- Personally, I dont see a disadvantage of posting them separate. Neither I would ever think that someone doing so would spam.